# Access data from indirect child table using LInq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have following table in my database and im accessing them through EF.

```
TestPack { id, name, type }
Sheets{ id, tp_id, date, rev }
Spool { id, sheet_id, date, rev, fabricated, installed }
```

which means a test pack has 1-M sheets and each sheet has 1-M spools. I want to get count of total Spools in the Test Pack, and count of spools that are fabricated, count of spools that are installed.

How do I get that through Linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you right,you would like to have something like this

```
 (from tp in ctx.TestPack
        join st in ctx.Sheets on st.tp_id equals tp.id
        join sl in ctx.Spool on sl.steet_id equals st.id
        where tp.id == testPackId //you can change or delete this condition
        select new {
          Total = sl.Count() , 
          FabricatedSpools = sl.Count(x=>x.fabricated == true),
          InstalledSpools = sl.Count(x=>x.installed == true)
     }).FisrtOrDefault();
```

Or maybe

```
 (from tp in ctx.TestPack
    join st in ctx.Sheets on st.tp_id equals tp.id
    join sl in ctx.Spool on sl.steet_id equals st.id
    where tp.id == testPackId //you can change or delete this condition
    select new {
      Total = sl.Count() , 
      FabricatedSpools = (from s in sl
        where s.fabricated == true    
        select s.Count()),
      InstalledSpools = (from i in sl
        where i.installed== true    
        select i.Count()),
 }).FisrtOrDefault();
```

Comment: Before Select filter the data on TestPack Id that's the OP requirement. nonetheless a good solution using sql syntax

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exact models are like but see below.

```
var testPackID = 2;//assuming

//assuming your DbContext is ctx;

var totalSpools = ctx.Spools.Count(x => x.Sheets.tp_id == testPackID);
var fabricatedSpools = ctx.Spools.Count(x => x.Sheets.tp_id == testPackID && x.fabricated);
var installedSpools = ctx.Spools.Count(x => x.Sheets.tp_id == testPackID && x.installed);
```

Comment: You need to join between the collections to get the TestPackId in the Spools collection

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Not necessarily .. he hasn't shown us the model yet but i've simply assumed that the Spool is related to sheets by sheet_id and the sheets is related to the TestPack by tp_id.

Comment: He has specified the relation between the three tables, they have FK constraints between them, what more is required

Answer (score 0):

[Sample data and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3131/20)

I had generated the queries in SQL Server and hope you can do in LINQ. if you want specifically in LINQ let me know.

And can you please clarify whether you want result in 3 or all the 3 results in one.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add some code, to explain your answer well, pointing to a link may not be the best option. I am not able to load the solution you have provided